# Jekyll Navigation - how to exclude pages

Tags: jekyll

Hey so I have built a multi-language website and I only want certain pages to show in the top navigation but they are showing in the navigation

This is what I have in my header.html

```
{% assign pages = site.pages | sort: "nav-order" %}
{% for p in pages %}
  {% if p.language == page.language %}
    <li><a class="tx--upper {% if p.url == page.url %}is-active{% endif %}" href="{{ p.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ p.title }}</a></li>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

And this is what I have in my yaml fontmatter for the page I want to be shown in the top navigation (about.html)

```
---
title: About
language: en
nav-order: 1
---
```

And this is what I have on my page that I don't want shown in top navigation (404.html)

```
---
language: en
nav-order: 
---
```

But show to I get it to check if `nav-order` is empty to not display in the top nav ? I have tried a `if` statement to check the assign `pages !== null` and also did a exclude from what I could find online but nothing has worked.

HELP[image]

Answer (score 1):

If if you only want to print page with a `nav-order:` set, you can just complement your condition like this :

```
{% if p.language == page.language and p.nav-order %}
```